# Oracle PL/SQL varchar2 parameter of a function is returning NULL value

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-macro

I have created a function that returns a table. This function has varchar2 parameter and the real surprising thing is that this parameter is returning NULL value and I cannot understnd what is going on here.

The purpose of this function is to execute a dynamic SQL query and return a table.

For simplicity, I have removed all the complicated lines of code. Below code is only returning the parameter value. I need to use this parameter in **IF BLOCK**. However, my if block always returns false and that is because parameter is getting NULL value.

```
create or replace function traudit04011 (
XPARAM IN VARCHAR2)
return clob sql_macro as
 
sql_statement varchar2(5000);
vc_condition varchar(1000);
p_search_by1 varchar(100) := '';
 
 
begin
 
   
IF  XPARAM is not NULL THEN 
vc_condition:='yes';
ELSE
vc_condition:='No';
END IF;
 
sql_statement := 'select ''' || vc_condition || ''' d1 from dual'; -- In real world, instead of XPARAM there will be a variable storing dynamic query
 
 
return sql_statement;
 
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('error');
 
 
end;
```

Now execute the above function :

```
select * from traudit04011('This is a parameter that always returns null')
```

What's wrong here. I have already spent 6 hours figuring this out. The strange part is that if I change the datatype of parameter to INT, the function starts working. :)

Any help would be appreciated..

[image]

Comment: It actually returns clob. It's a 1000 lines of code. It's only to make it simple I removed every thing

Comment: @Abra: I cannot use select traudit04011('This is a parameter that always returns null') from dual. This function has to return a table. It has to be select * from. This function in real word will return 15 columns

Comment: @Abra 100% sure. Just change the parameter datatype to int and u will see

Comment: @Abra: FYI..I Just replaced clob with varchar2 and output is still the same, NULL. My question is simple why parameter is returning NULL value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the Input parameter in the query with normal string concatenation.

You need to use `function_name.input_variable_name` directly in the dynamic query as follows:

```
sql_statement := 'select traudit04011.XPARAM d1 from dual';
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7cUoM1RZ)

Comment: Thank you so much. That solves one problem. However, there is another issue. If block still returns "No". In this case as parameter is not null it should return "yes". I  have updated my code.

Comment: Again, Use `function_name.input_variable_name` in the IF condition. -->  https://dbfiddle.uk/oeNuBx9t

Comment: Can you advise how to use variable with concatenation - I need to use this - 'select  ''' || vc_condition || ''' d1 from dual'; ----> https://dbfiddle.uk/EfeY7waY

Comment: Whenever you want to use the input variable name, use it directly in the query other portion can be used via concatenation.  `'..... function_name.input_variable_name =  ' || 123 || ' .....'`

Comment: I give up. I tried everything but I am not getting "start: Yes". --> https://dbfiddle.uk/yKPUM8BP. something is wrong with traudit04011.XPARAM IS NOT NULL. It's going to else statement

Comment: You need to provide pure expression as follows: https://dbfiddle.uk/dZGDCkkY